# Name hiding in c++

Tags: terminology

What exactly is name hiding in c++? what are the advantages? 
i already went through a couple of links but couldn't get a proper explanation for the same.

Comment: Can you post some of the links you went through?

Comment: @Ryan Could you be more careful with your reviews, please? This one is, IMO, an off-topic programming question. [This other one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/25090), which you also reviewed recently as "No action needed" doesn't even answer the question. Part of the point of reviewing is to make sure that new content meets the standards the community expects of the site. If you're not familiar with those standards, it might be better to wait before reviewing more posts.

Comment: Welcome to SE Computer Science. Questions about the specifics of a programming language are off-topic. unless the programming language serves only to illustrate a general conceptual issue. Besides, you are expected to give soe precision about the work you have done, or the documents you have read, so that we get some context on what remains unclear to you.

Comment: @Ryan And now you've reviewed [a blatantly off-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130339/how-does-fread-work) as "No action needed". Please, this is not helping the site. In fact, it's creating more work for other people because now, when I see your name in the first posts review summary, I have to go check what you did. Please stop reviewing until you are familiar with what is and is not on-topic at CS.SE.